# Solr Replication leaking some memory?

Tags: java, solr, out-of-memory, jboss7.x, replication

Lately we have discovered that the JBoss process on our Linux server was shut down by OS, due to high memory consumption (about 2.3 GB). Here is the dump:

```
RPC: fragment too large: 0x00800103
RPC: multiple fragments per record not supported
RPC: fragment too large: 0x00800103
RPC: multiple fragments per record not supported
RPC: fragment too large: 0x00800103
RPC: multiple fragments per record not supported
RPC: fragment too large: 0x00800103
RPC: multiple fragments per record not supported
RPC: fragment too large: 0x00800103
RPC: multiple fragments per record not supported
RPC: fragment too large: 0x00800103
RPC: multiple fragments per record not supported
RPC: fragment too large: 0x00800103
RPC: multiple fragments per record not supported
java invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x201da, order=0, oom_adj=0, oom_score_adj=0
java cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
Pid: 11445, comm: java Not tainted 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64 #1
Call Trace:
 [<ffffffff810d05b1>] ? cpuset_print_task_mems_allowed+0x91/0xb0
 [<ffffffff81122960>] ? dump_header+0x90/0x1b0
 [<ffffffff8122798c>] ? security_real_capable_noaudit+0x3c/0x70
 [<ffffffff81122de2>] ? oom_kill_process+0x82/0x2a0
 [<ffffffff81122d21>] ? select_bad_process+0xe1/0x120
 [<ffffffff81123220>] ? out_of_memory+0x220/0x3c0
 [<ffffffff8112fb3c>] ? __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x8ac/0x8d0
 [<ffffffff81167a9a>] ? alloc_pages_current+0xaa/0x110
 [<ffffffff8111fd57>] ? __page_cache_alloc+0x87/0x90
 [<ffffffff8111f73e>] ? find_get_page+0x1e/0xa0
 [<ffffffff81120cf7>] ? filemap_fault+0x1a7/0x500
 [<ffffffff8114a084>] ? __do_fault+0x54/0x530
 [<ffffffff810afa17>] ? futex_wait+0x227/0x380
 [<ffffffff8114a657>] ? handle_pte_fault+0xf7/0xb00
 [<ffffffff8114b28a>] ? handle_mm_fault+0x22a/0x300
 [<ffffffff8104a8d8>] ? __do_page_fault+0x138/0x480
 [<ffffffff81527910>] ? thread_return+0x4e/0x76e
 [<ffffffff8152d45e>] ? do_page_fault+0x3e/0xa0
 [<ffffffff8152a815>] ? page_fault+0x25/0x30
Mem-Info:
Node 0 DMA per-cpu:
CPU    0: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
CPU    1: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Node 0 DMA32 per-cpu:
CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 178
CPU    1: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:  30
Node 0 Normal per-cpu:
CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 174
CPU    1: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 194
active_anon:113513 inactive_anon:184789 isolated_anon:0
 active_file:21 inactive_file:0 isolated_file:0
 unevictable:0 dirty:10 writeback:0 unstable:0
 free:17533 slab_reclaimable:4706 slab_unreclaimable:8059
 mapped:64 shmem:4 pagetables:3064 bounce:0
Node 0 DMA free:15696kB min:248kB low:308kB high:372kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:15300kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:0kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:0kB slab_unreclaimable:0kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:0kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? yes
lowmem_reserve[]: 0 3000 4010 4010
Node 0 DMA32 free:41740kB min:50372kB low:62964kB high:75556kB active_anon:200648kB inactive_anon:216504kB active_file:20kB inactive_file:52kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:3072160kB mlocked:0kB dirty:8kB writeback:0kB mapped:168kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:3720kB slab_unreclaimable:2476kB kernel_stack:512kB pagetables:516kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:108 all_unreclaimable? yes
lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 1010 1010
Node 0 Normal free:12696kB min:16956kB low:21192kB high:25432kB active_anon:253404kB inactive_anon:522652kB active_file:64kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:1034240kB mlocked:0kB dirty:32kB writeback:0kB mapped:88kB shmem:16kB slab_reclaimable:15104kB slab_unreclaimable:29760kB kernel_stack:3704kB pagetables:11740kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:146 all_unreclaimable? yes
lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
Node 0 DMA: 4*4kB 2*8kB 3*16kB 4*32kB 2*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 1*1024kB 1*2048kB 3*4096kB = 15696kB
Node 0 DMA32: 341*4kB 277*8kB 209*16kB 128*32kB 104*64kB 54*128kB 33*256kB 13*512kB 0*1024kB 1*2048kB 0*4096kB = 41740kB
Node 0 Normal: 2662*4kB 0*8kB 0*16kB 0*32kB 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 1*2048kB 0*4096kB = 12696kB
64603 total pagecache pages
64549 pages in swap cache
Swap cache stats: add 3763837, delete 3699288, find 1606527/1870160
Free swap  = 0kB
Total swap = 1048568kB
1048560 pages RAM
67449 pages reserved
1061 pages shared
958817 pages non-shared
[ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss cpu oom_adj oom_score_adj name
[  419]     0   419     2662        1   1     -17         -1000 udevd
[  726]     0   726     2697        1   1     -17         -1000 udevd
[ 1021]     0  1021     4210       40   1       0             0 vmware-guestd
[ 1238]     0  1238    23294       28   1     -17         -1000 auditd
[ 1254]    65  1254   112744      203   1       0             0 nslcd
[ 1267]     0  1267    62271      123   1       0             0 rsyslogd
[ 1279]     0  1279     2705       32   1       0             0 irqbalance
[ 1293]    32  1293     4744       16   1       0             0 rpcbind
[ 1311]    29  1311     5837        2   0       0             0 rpc.statd
[ 1422]    81  1422     5874       36   0       0             0 dbus-daemon
[ 1451]     0  1451     1020        1   0       0             0 acpid
[ 1460]    68  1460     9995      129   0       0             0 hald
[ 1461]     0  1461     5082        2   1       0             0 hald-runner
[ 1490]     0  1490     5612        2   1       0             0 hald-addon-inpu
[ 1503]    68  1503     4484        2   0       0             0 hald-addon-acpi
[ 1523]     0  1523   134268       53   0       0             0 automount
[ 1540]     0  1540     1566        1   0       0             0 mcelog
[ 1552]     0  1552    16651       27   1     -17         -1000 sshd
[ 1560]     0  1560     5545       26   0       0             0 xinetd
[ 1568]    38  1568     8202       33   0       0             0 ntpd
[ 1584]     0  1584    21795       56   0       0             0 sendmail
[ 1592]    51  1592    19658       32   0       0             0 sendmail
[ 1601]     0  1601    29324       21   1       0             0 crond
[ 1612]     0  1612     5385        5   1       0             0 atd
[ 1638]     0  1638     1016        2   0       0             0 mingetty
[ 1640]     0  1640     1016        2   1       0             0 mingetty
[ 1642]     0  1642     1016        2   0       0             0 mingetty
[ 1644]     0  1644     2661        1   1     -17         -1000 udevd
[ 1645]     0  1645     1016        2   0       0             0 mingetty
[ 1647]     0  1647     1016        2   1       0             0 mingetty
[ 1649]     0  1649     1016        2   1       0             0 mingetty
[25003]     0 25003    26827        1   1       0             0 rpc.rquotad
[25007]     0 25007     5440        2   1       0             0 rpc.mountd
[25045]     0 25045     5773        2   1       0             0 rpc.idmapd
[31756]     0 31756    43994       12   0       0             0 httpd
[31758]    48 31758    45035      205   0       0             0 httpd
[31759]    48 31759    45035      210   1       0             0 httpd
[31760]    48 31760    45035      201   1       0             0 httpd
[31761]    48 31761    45068      211   1       0             0 httpd
[31762]    48 31762    45068      199   0       0             0 httpd
[31763]    48 31763    45035      196   0       0             0 httpd
[31764]    48 31764    45068      191   1       0             0 httpd
[31765]    48 31765    45035      206   1       0             0 httpd
[ 1893]     0  1893    41344        2   0       0             0 su
[ 1896]   500  1896    26525        2   0       0             0 standalone.sh
[ 1957]   500  1957   570217    81589   0       0             0 java
[10739]     0 10739    41344        2   0       0             0 su
[10742]   500 10742    26525        2   0       0             0 standalone.sh
[10805]   500 10805   576358    77163   0       0             0 java
[13378]     0 13378    41344        2   0       0             0 su
[13381]   500 13381    26525        2   1       0             0 standalone.sh
[13442]   500 13442   561881    73430   1       0             0 java
Out of memory: Kill process 10805 (java) score 141 or sacrifice child
Killed process 10805, UID 500, (java) total-vm:2305432kB, anon-rss:308648kB, file-rss:4kB
```

It was shut down at about 04:00 in the morning, when there were no users and no activity on the server, besides Solr replication. It was the master node, which has failed, and our slave pings it every minute. Here is the replication config:

```
<requestHandler name="/replication" class="solr.ReplicationHandler" >
       <lst name="master">
         <str name="enable">${solr.enable.master:false}</str>
         <str name="replicateAfter">commit</str>
         <str name="replicateAfter">startup</str>
         <str name="confFiles">schema.xml,stopwords.txt</str>
       </lst>
       <lst name="slave">
         <str name="enable">${solr.enable.slave:false}</str>
         <str name="masterUrl">${solr.master.url:http://localhost:8080/solr/cstb}</str>
         <str name="pollInterval">00:00:60</str>
       </lst>
     </requestHandler>
```

Since there were no users activity there were no changes in indexes and thus Solr should not actually do anything (I assume).

Some other values from config file:

```
  <indexDefaults>
    <useCompoundFile>false</useCompoundFile>
    <mergeFactor>10</mergeFactor>
    <ramBufferSizeMB>32</ramBufferSizeMB>
    <maxFieldLength>10000</maxFieldLength>
    <writeLockTimeout>1000</writeLockTimeout>
    <lockType>native</lockType>
  </indexDefaults>

  <mainIndex>
    <useCompoundFile>false</useCompoundFile>
    <ramBufferSizeMB>32</ramBufferSizeMB>
    <mergeFactor>10</mergeFactor>
    <unlockOnStartup>false</unlockOnStartup>
    <reopenReaders>true</reopenReaders>
    <deletionPolicy class="solr.SolrDeletionPolicy">
      <str name="maxCommitsToKeep">1</str>
      <str name="maxOptimizedCommitsToKeep">0</str>
    </deletionPolicy>
    <infoStream file="INFOSTREAM.txt">false</infoStream>
  </mainIndex>

  <queryResultWindowSize>20</queryResultWindowSize>
  <queryResultMaxDocsCached>200</queryResultMaxDocsCached>
```

So, have anybody experienced similar situation or have any thoughts about it? We are using Solr 3.5.

Comment: Can you share the heap size configuration for your JVM, type of linux, operating system version and hardware config (specifically memory)?

Comment: @JohnPetrone There is nothing special (unfortunately I don't have all the system settings at my fingertips). Max heap size for jboss is set to 512 MB. And I've probably stated it in the wrong way: there was a total memory consumption by all jvm processes 2.3GB, not by jboss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into a low memory condition that is causing Linux to kill off a high memory usage process:

```
Out of memory: Kill process 10805 (java) score 141 or sacrifice child
```

This is known as the out of memory killer or OOM. Given that you are only using 512MB for heap for the JVM (way too low in my opinion for a production Solr instance of any significant capacity) you don't have a lot of options as you cannot reduce heap to free up more OS memory.

Things you can try:

1. Upgrade to a larger server with more memory. This would be my number one recommendation - you simply don't have enough memory available.
2. Move any other production code to another system. You did not
   mention if you have anything else running on this server but I would
   move anything I could elsewhere. Not a lot to gain here as I suspect
   your system is quite small to being with, but every little bit
   helps.
3. Try tuning the OOM killer to be less strict - not that easy to do and I don't know what you will gain due to overall low server size but you can always experiment:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58872/how-to-set-oom-killer-adjustments-for-daemons-permanently

http://backdrift.org/how-to-create-oom-killer-exceptions

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-dev/oom-killer-1911807.html

Comment: I agree with your first option. Our Linux server (fortunately, it is not a production server) has 4 GB ram and contains 3 jbosses for different systems (training, test, integration), each started with 512 MB. Server itself is not under high pressure and is fairly simple. But our admin says he don't wont to add more memory, because before replication was switched on, everything worked fine. So, I was wondering what's up with Solr and if it is leaking some memory or something, or there is some kind of GC bug (I actually found one reference on Solr mailing list, but it should be fixed in our jvm)

Comment: No not a bug or a memory leak - you've just been lucky. You are running right at the limit and when the OS decides it needs memory the OOM killer is going to go thru a set process to kill a high memory user.